# Why doesn't this sed statement work?

Tags: regex, sed

I have been working with regular expressions for the past couple days in class. I cannot determine why this expression doesn't work.  I am looking for expressions like the following:

```
value = (struct node){ 5, NULL};
value2 = (structname){ 1, 2 }; 
*pointer = ( bla ){3,4};
```

Here is the expression I am using:

```
sed -n '/^[*0-9A-Za-z_]+ *= *( *[0-9A-Za-z_]+ *[0-9A-Za-z_]* *) *{[0-9A-Za-z, ]};/p'     structfile
```

What am I missing because it returns nothing.  Also a side note I have used [^,] in some expressions and I still get lines with , s.  What am I missing?

Comment: Wow I don't know what I did wrong but yea all of your solutions work.  I guess I am just dumb.  Thank you all so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `+`; and fix `{[0-9A-Za-z, ]}` to `{[0-9A-Za-z, ]*}`.

```
sed -n '/^[*0-9A-Za-z_]\+ *= *( *[0-9A-Za-z_]\+ *[0-9A-Za-z_]* *) *{[0-9A-Za-z, ]*};/p' structfile


me@localhost:~$ cat structfile 
value = (struct node){ 5, NULL};
value2 = (structname){ 1, 2 }; 
*pointer = ( bla ){3,4};
not astruct
notastructstr =

me@localhost:~$ sed -n '/^[*0-9A-Za-z_]\+ *= *( *[0-9A-Za-z_]\+ *[0-9A-Za-z_]* *) *{[0-9A-Za-z, ]*};/p' structfile
value = (struct node){ 5, NULL};
value2 = (structname){ 1, 2 }; 
*pointer = ( bla ){3,4};
```

Comment: Nope tried it. I swear nothing works. I have tried so so many things.

Comment: Not all versions of sed recognize `+` as a special character.  Instead of `[*0-9A-Za-z_]\+`, use `[*0-9A-Za-z_][*0-9A-Za-z_]*`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\S\+\s\+=\s\+(\s*\S\+\(\s\+\S\+\)\?\s*){\s*\S\+\s*,\s*\S\+\s*};/!d' file
```

- Start by building a loose regexp using only whitespace (`\s`), non-whitespace (`\S`) and literals (`=`,`(`,`)`,`{`,`}` and `;`)
- Determine if the above are 1-or-more, zero-or-more or zero-or-one e.g. one-or-more whitespace would be represented by `\s\+`, zero-or-more non-whitespace would be `\S*` and zero-or-one grouped would be `\(\s\+\S\+\)\?`
- Try and anchor the regexp using `^` for start of string, `$` end of string and in a multiline regexp `\n` for newline
- Build the regexp slowly, left to right, checking each piece as you go along
- Once you have a working version replace individual whitespace/non-whitespace by more specific character classes
- Further refine the one-or-more classes to a specific range or number e.g. one-to-three (`\{1,3\}`) or 3 (`\{3\}`) of course a single class, literal or group need not be qualified

HTH